# Is the first parameter of a static method referring to the class it is called on?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I saw these lines of codes in a repo and I was wondering what that `Cls` in `Method2` is referring to?

```
   class TestClass {
      static Method1(...args) {
        return TestClass.Method2(...args);
      }

      static async Method2(Cls, ...args) {
        Cls.someStuff();
      }
    }
```

There is nothing passed as `Cls` into `Method2` from `Method1`, what is that `Cls` referring to in this case?

I'm guessing `Cls` is going to be `TestClass` but I'm not sure if it's really the case where the first parameter of `Method2` will always be the class which it is called on?

Comment: It all depends on how `Method1` is being called, which doesn't look to be in the code here. Regardless of the code, it would be *weird* for the first parameter to be the class itself, because you can reference the class with `this` instead. It also looks like `TestClass` doesn't have a `someStuff` method (static or otherwise)

Comment: @CertainPerformance From what I see, `Method1` is only being called like `TestClass.Method1({name: 'jane'})` which makes me wonder what `Cls` is going to be. I was thinking if there is something I don't know about static classes in ES6.

Comment: In that case, `Cls` would be the object, that is `{name: 'jane'}`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh.. When it is put it as `Method2(Cls, ...args)`, are we actually destructuring the `...args` from `Method1`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance And if it was called this way `TestClass.Method1({name: 'jane'}, 'hello')`, does it mean `Cls` in `Method2` would be `{name: 'jane'}` and `args` in `Method2` would be `args[0] = 'hello'`?

Comment: No destructuring, that's rest/spread syntax. The `Method2` definition takes the first argument and puts it into a variable named `Cls`. It looks like no second argument is being passed, so `args` in `Method2` will be an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Method1`, the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) collects all the parameters passed to the method and puts it into an array called `args`. It then calls the second method with the same arguments by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `args`.

`Method2` gets the first argument passed to a separate variable and collects the rest of the arguments passed to a variable called `args`.

```js
class TestClass {
  static Method1(...args) {
    console.log("Method 1 args: ", args) // ["arg 1", "arg 2", "arg 3"]
    return TestClass.Method2(...args);
  }

  static Method2(Cls, ...args) {
    console.log("Cls: ", Cls); // "arg 1"
    console.log("Method 2 args: ", args) // ["arg 2", "arg 3"]
  }
}

TestClass.Method1("arg 1", "arg 2", "arg 3")
```